# Getting Action controller UNKNOWN FORMAT error- for rails 4 + AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to do a remote search in a ajax form, where the user types into a code, and submits via ajax, the controller gets the code and see if anything in the database matches, then controller then returns a response appropriately. I keep getting an UNKNOW `ActionController::UnknownFormat` when I try to search.

Here is my controller action

```
class TenantsController < ApplicationController


def search
@count = 0
@property = Property.find_by_propertyid(params[:propertyid])
@current_tenant =current_tenant
if @property
  toast('success', "#{@property.propertyid}")
  @current_tenant.landlord_id = @property.landlord_id
  @current_tenant.property_id = @property.id
  @current_tenant.save



  redirect_to authenticated_tenant_path
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end

  redirect_to authenticated_tenant_path

end
```

end

here is my view template form

```
           <%= form_tag({controller: "tenants", action: "search", remote:true,}, method: "get") do %>
                  <%= label_tag(:propertyid, "Search for:") %>
                  <%= text_field_tag(:propertyid) %>
                  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
           <% end %>
```

here is the route file

```
  match '/tenant/search' => "tenants#search",via: [:get, :post]
```

I have a search.js.erb with a simple `alert('i am here')`

here is the error log

```
Started GET "/tenants/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-29 21:54:33 -0400
Processing by Tenant::RegistrationsController#edit as JS
  Tenant Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."id" = 27 ORDER BY "tenants"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Tprofile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tprofiles".* FROM "tprofiles" WHERE "tprofiles"."tenant_id" = 27 LIMIT 1
  Rendered tenantprofiles/_edit.html.erb (3.7ms)
  Rendered tenants/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/dash_tenants (30.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/tenants/_dash_side.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/tenants/_dash_header.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 88ms (Views: 77.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


Started GET "/tenant/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&propertyid=a&commit=Search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-29 21:54:35 -0400
Processing by TenantsController#search as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "propertyid"=>"a", "commit"=>"Search"}
  Tenant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tenants".* FROM "tenants" WHERE "tenants"."id" = 27 ORDER BY "tenants"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Property Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."propertyid" = 'a' LIMIT 1
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 7ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:372:in `retrieve_collector_from_mimes'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:189:in `respond_to'
  app/controllers/tenants_controller.rb:38:in `search'
```

but I dont even get there. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you are responding... and then doing a toast then a redirect *after* that. your response should be the response - whether a render or a redirect... you shouldn't be doing anything after that.

Comment: im not worry about the toast notification. that was put in there before I started doing ajax. The controller gets stuck on Unknown fomat, and stops everything

Comment: You asked what you are doing wrong, I told you what you are doing wrong, you can't just "not worry about it"... what I described is the thing that is breaking your code and 'stopping everything" ;)

You cannot redirect *after* the response-section. you should be redirecting *inside* the response-section... inside the format.html (which you seem to have missed)